# Jquery Select all elements with data attribute common name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to select all the inputs in my form that have a data attribute with a similar name.

This is my form:

```
<form id = "myForm">
  <input name="name" data-valid-presence=true >
  <input name="age" data-valid-biggerThan="18" >
  <input name="email[0]" data-valid-email=true >
  <input name="email[1]" data-valid-email=true >
</form>
```

and my jQuery selector is:

```
var inputs = jQuery("#myForm").find("input[data-valid-email],[data-valid-length],[data-valid-presence], [data-valid-biggerThan]");
```

I'm looking for a way to select all the inputs that have a `data-valid-*` in them without having to find them one by one like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.filter:

```
var inputs = $('form').find('input').filter(function() {
    var matched = false;
    $.each(this.attributes, function(attr) {
        if ( matched ) return;
        matched = /^data-valid/.test(this.name);
    });
    return matched;
});
```